# How to add additional attributes to a class?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

How would I add additional locationx and locationy variables to the lists while the program is running?

Example of the class:

```
class Building:
    'Common base class for all buildings'

    def __init__(self, name, hp, img, locationx, locationy, height, width):
        self.name = name
        self.hp = hp
        self.img = img
        self.locationx = locationx
        self.locationy = locationy
        self.height = height
        self.width = width

building_shipyard = Building("Shipyard",500,shipyard,[1000,2500,5000],[1000,2500,5000],300,300)
```

For instance, after a user places a new building, I might want self.locationx and self.locationy to be updated from [1000,2500,5000] to [1000,2500,5000,7000].

Comment: Note that your title is misleading. You're not adding new attributes at all. Instead, you just want to `.append()` to a list.

Comment: `building_shipyard.locationx.append(7000)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just access these attributes:

```
...
def place_building ():
    global building_shipyard 
    ...
    building_shipyard.locationx =  [1000,2500,5000,7000]
    # or
    building_shipyard.locationx.append(7000)
```